# allow just one user to access to his account in the same computer

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have this problem with my login system.
I have two users, userA and userB in the same computer. userA enters to his account in one browser; userB gets access to his account in the same browser. My system thinks that now userB is also userA and userA is still connected to its own account but his name appears as userB. If these two users get access into different browsers, there is NO problem.

Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem?
Here is the code of my login system:

```
<?php session_start();

 $error = "";
 $usuario1="";
 $password="";
 $form = $_POST['acceso_cuenta'];

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $usuario1  = $_POST['login'];
    $password1 = $_POST['pass'];

        $strconn="dbname=postgres port=5432 host=127.0.0.1 user=xxx password=***";
        $conn=pg_Connect($strconn);

if(!$conn){
 //  "Error connection!!!";  

}else{

  $query3 = "SELECT USUARIO FROM USERS WHERE USUARIO='$usuario1' 
      AND E_CONTRASENIA='$password' AND LEVEL='TAMER_LEVEL_3'";

  $query2 = "SELECT USUARIO FROM USERS WHERE USUARIO='$usuario1' 
      AND E_CONTRASENIA='$password' AND LEVEL='TAMER_LEVEL_2'";

      $result2=pg_query($conn,$query2);

      $result3=pg_query($conn,$query3);

         if(pg_num_rows($result3) != 0 ) { //success
             if(isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || isset($_SESSION['user'])){
                   session_unset();
                   session_destroy();
                   }

             $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
             $_SESSION['user']=$usuario1;
             header('location: http://localhost/public_html/teacherLv3.php');   
             exit;

          }else if(pg_num_rows($result2) != 0){
             if(isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || isset($_SESSION['user'])){
                   session_unset();
                   session_destroy();
                   }

         $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
         $_SESSION['user']=$usuario1; 
         header('location: http://localhost/public_html/teacherLv2.php');   
         exit;  

       }else { 

           $error = "WRONG DATA."; 
       }//
    pg_close($conn);

  } //else { $error = 'Don't leave blank spaces';}
 }//end of if server
 ?>
```

This is the code for teacherLv3's page:

```
<?php
session_start();

// is the one accessing this page logged in or not?

 if ( (!isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true)) {

// not logged in, move to login page
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
  }
?>

<html>
  <?  echo "Welcome back Teacher_Level 3 MASTER  {$_SESSION['user']} " ; ?>
</html>
```

This is the code for teacherLv2's page:

```
// is the one accessing this page logged in or not?

 if ( (!isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) && $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true)) {

// not logged in, move to login page
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
  }
?>

<html>
  <?  echo "Welcome back Teacher_Level 2 MASTER  {$_SESSION['user']} " ; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: At the login you must `unset` the session variable. Then the problem is gone... -btw- On your `lvl2` page you say `welcome on lvl3` and visa versa...

Comment: Also, use `session_start` always at the begin of the page ( right after the php open tag). And mayby you want to add an session variable with the `acces lvl` to ;)

Comment: At the login? You mean once the user got access to his account?

Comment: Yes, i will make an answer for it to clearify it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first... It's an good practise to start the session at top of the page. so right after the first `<?php` tag you start the session `session_start();`

Then you need to unset the session variable first if an user is already logged in.

So at the moment that you logout, you can do this:

```
// everything fine for logout???
session_unset();
session_destroy();
// rederict to login / home page or whatever...
```

And at the login part:

```
if(pg_num_rows($result3) != 0 ) { //success
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || isset($_SESSION['user']){
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user']=$usuario1;
    header('location: http://localhost/public_html/teacherLv3.php');   
    exit;
}else if(pg_num_rows($result2) != 0){
    if(isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || isset($_SESSION['user']){
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
        }   
    $_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user']=$usuario1; 
    header('location: http://localhost/public_html/teacherLv2.php');   
    exit;  
}
```

**EDIT**

First you need to create an unique string for the user ( at the login part ):

```
$r_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$unique_string = hash('ripemd160', $user_agent . $r_addr);
```

Then you need to create an table in the database that can hold the `username` ( to know about which user where talking about ) and the `unique_string` and an column where you set `0 or 1` for logout or not ( default 0 );

Then when you login, you check against the database if there's already any user with the `unique_string`, if so, update them ( except your own ) and set the `logout column` to 1. Then check if you with that `unique_string` already excist, if so, then delete that entry. Then insert your own data in the table.

Then everywhere where your check if the user is logged in, you also do an query on the new made table where you get the logout status ( so check for the `username` and for the `unique_string` ). The status is `0` or `1`. then you do a little if:

```
if(logout_status == 1 || no_result){ // also check for no result, because if so you an unregisterd user. The safest way to handle this is to logout and login again...
    // Do the logout with session_unset, session_destroy
}
```

Comment: the user needs to dropped from his account once another user gets access to his account in the same browser.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I've been stick with this problem for around 5 hours alone...

Comment: @user119177, i updated the answer again. Got some extra fault checks in the `login` and in the `check if user is logged in` part

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I am already coding your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just prevent anyone else from logging in when there is already someone logged i?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && empty($_SESSION['logged-in'])) {
    /* ... */
}
```